# Accessing C arrays(int[], float[], etc..) using Objective-C runtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, runtime

I'm trying to save all the variables in my class into `NSUserDefaults` using objc/runtime. And below is the code I'm using.

```
NSUInteger count;
Ivar *iVars = class_copyIvarList([self class], &count);
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<count; i++) 
{
    Ivar var    = iVars[i];
    NSString *varName = [NSString stringWithCString:ivar_getName(var) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *varType = [NSString stringWithCString:ivar_getTypeEncoding(var) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if([varType hasPrefix:@"["])
    {
        NSLog(@"Array");
        id var1 = [_manager valueForKey:varName];

        NSLog(@"--- %@", var1);

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&([_manager valueForKey:varName]) length:sizeof([_manager valueForKey:varName])]
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[_manager valueForKey:varName] forKey:varName];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"NonArray");
        NSLog(@"---  %@", [_manager valueForKey:varName]);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[_manager valueForKey:varName] forKey:varName];
    }

}

free(iVars);
```

The problem is that, when there are only primitive datatypes, the above code works just fine. But, when I try to access a array variable like `int[]`, or `float[]`, it gets crashed with `SIGABRT`. it is not showing any other messages.

`valueForKey` doesn't return any values for C arrays.

If anybody know how to load values for C-arrays in runtime, please help.

Thanks in advance,

Suran

Comment: Try using objectForKey instead of valueForKey.

Comment: But, my class is a subclass of NSObject, not any class like NSMutableDictionary etc, and when I try to use objectForKey it is just showing a warning that, it can't find the method

Answer (score 2):

Unless you always provide a paired length method, your program will never know the length of the array returned. So... you will need to do some work someplace to accomplish this without a crash.

If I really wanted to do what you're doing, I would make the class itself create the array, providing `NSData`. If this is common, you may want to use a convention:

```
 - (int*)pixelBuffer;
 - (NSData *)pixelBufferForSerialization; // << returns a deep copy of
                                          //    self.pixelBuffer as an
                                          //    NSData instance.
```

So your above implementation would see that the property defines a scalar array, and then request `NSData * data = obj.pixelBufferForSerialization;` instead of trying to produce the data itself.

**Update**

It's best to let the class do it. Here's how to create `NSData` using such an array:

```
@interface DataManager : NSObject
{
@private
    int* things;
    size_t nThings;
}

- (int*)things;
- (NSData *)thingsAsNSData;

@end

@implementation DataManager

- (int*)things
{
    return things;
}

- (NSData *)thingsAsNSData
{
    // note: you may need to choose an endianness for serialization
    if (0 == nThings) return [NSData data];w
    return [NSData dataWithBytes:things length:nThings * sizeof(things[0])];
}

@end
```

Again - you want the class to create the data because it knows its own structure best.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for the answer but, I didn't get you. Can you explain, how can I achieve this?

Comment: @Suran C arrays don't define length, so you need to save the length someplace. So you need to also keep track of the length of the buffer - it's easiest for the class itself to manage the buffer *and* the buffer's length. So the easy way would be to move the creation of the `NSData` to the class because it should know the length. Then you can create a convention (I suggested a suffix *property*`ForSerialization`) for returning deep copies of the buffers as `NSData` (outlined above). Then you can compose a string from selector+suffix, and then convert that string to a selector to get the data.

Comment: Can you post some code regarding this? I'm not able to grasp it. Also, to get the size of the array, can't we just use sizeof operator?

Comment: @Suran a) I don't know specifically what code you want (to avoid writing everything, which takes time) b) the `sizeof` operator will not work - it will return the size of a pointer regardless of the number of elements in the array.

Comment: The thing is that, what I'm trying to accomplish is to get the value of an C array that is a property of the class 'DataManager' of which,  '_manager' is an instance. I've saved the property name and property type into two variables varName and varType respectively. Now, I need to retrieve the state of that C array. I'd be really thankful if you can provide me with some sample code to get the value of the C array.